# Kleene positive closure - help in proofing this claim

Tags: formal-languages, closure-properties

I just started a course called 'Automata and Formal Languages'. 
I'm having difficulty in proofing\disproofing this equality.

$ (L_{1} \circ L_{2})^{+} = L_{1}^{+} \circ L_{2}^{+}
 $

Where:

$ L_{1} $, $L_{2}$ are Languages.

$\circ$ is the concatenation operation between two languages.

$+$ is the Kleene plus closure defined by $\bigcup  _{i = 1}^{\infty }L^{i} $

I tried finding a counter example and also tried to formally proof but had no luck.
Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

Comment: In the proving part, what, specifically, have you tried and where, specifically, did you get stuck? In the disproving part, what kind of examples did you look at? Hint: try very simple languages first.

Comment: What happens if $L_1$ and $L_2$ each consists of a single string?

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for responding. Appreanty I tried every example but the simplest on :). When I picked 
$ L_{1} = \left \{a  \right \}, L_{2} = \left \{b  \right \} $ its fairly easy to disproof the claim. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use $A$ for $L_1$ and $B$ for $L_2$.
If you unpack both sides, you get
$$
(AB)^+ = AB + ABAB + ABABAB + \cdots \\
A^+B^+ = AB + AAB + ABB + AABB + \cdots
$$
Perhaps this can give you some ideas.